# Build Cordova project in visual studio 2015 , images issue

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have an existing, working Cordova project.
I am trying to load it now with visual studio 2015 RTM.

when debug with ripple it looks fine, but when opening with android emulator all pictures are missing. the same happens when I publish in release mode.
on javascript console I get this error on all images:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

example:

```
<img class="logoImg" src="images/logo.png" height="100" />
```

please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check the capitalization, because Android is based on Linux and this system is case sensitive.

So maybe you have to correct the filename (**L**ogo.png) or the path (**I**mages):

```
<img class="logoImg" src="Images/Logo.png" height="100" />
```